# Regexp find a match with priority order but same captured group

Tags: regex, pcre2

I have the same problem as the one in the link but in PCRE2 (regex101.com):

[Regexp find a match with priority order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836985/regexp-find-a-match-with-priority-order)

I have:

```
/.*?(hello)|.*?(hey)|.*?(hi)/ms

hi hey hello
```

But the problem is that when it finds `hello`, it is stored in group 1, when it finds `hey` in group 2, and when it finds `hi` in group 3, I want only group 1 to be used instead.
How do I get this?

https://regex101.com/r/bc8XQE/1

Comment: Like this? `.*?\b(hello|hey|hi)\b`

Comment: Similar, but obviously taking only the one with higher priority, which in my example is `hello`.

Comment: Like this then? `.*?\Khello|.*?\Khey|.*?\Khi` https://regex101.com/r/MrUN1F/1

Comment: No wait WTF, ahahahaha, how did you do?

Comment: Almost, there is the problem that when I write `hi hey hehehello` it doesn't find me `hey` but still `hello`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PCRE, instead of 3 different groups, you can use your pattern with the 3 alternatives and then make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

The word boundary `\b` prevents a partial word match.

```
.*?\K\bhello\b|.*?\K\bhey\b|.*?\K\bhi\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YVfgeW/1).

If you really must have group 1, then you can use a branch reset group:

```
(?|.*?\b(hello)\b|.*?\b(hey)\b|.*?\b(hi)\b)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xMkmuW/1).

Comment: Yes, this solution is perfect. With only match is also better.

Comment: I would need the `/ms` flags to use with grep in a form that looks like this: `grep -P -- '/.*?\K\bhello\b|.*?\K\bhey\b|.*?\K\bhi\b/ms'`, which of course does not give the desired result. How do I set the same flags I use on regex101 in grep on bash?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo You don't need the forward slashes, and use `-o` to get only the match `grep -Po '.*?\K\bhello\b|.*?\K\bhey\b|.*?\K\bhi\b' file`

Comment: in case there are newlines to separate the words rather than spaces, I must also use the `z` option and the `s` modifier: `grep -Pzo -- '(?s).*?\K\bhello\b|.*?\K\bhey\b|.*?\K\bhi\b'` but sadly the actual modifiers would be `gms` when all I need is `ms`. The `-m 1` option has no effect because of the `z` option and deleting the modifier only works for example with `(?-m)`, which leaves `gs` and with `(?-s) `, which leaves `gm` but not with `(?-g)` which oddly gives an error. The solution would be `(?s-g)` (add `s`, remove `g`) but it doesn't like the letter `g` at all.

Comment: `m` is not needed in my case, you are right. The `s` flag even with the `-z` option strangely has the desired effect. The problem is just `g`.

Comment: Your demo output shows: `hellohellohellohello` due of `g` modifier. So the underlying problem should be `grep only the first match and stop`, which is also an already existing topic on stackoverflow, which unfortunately didn't help me.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo There is no `g` modifier, using `-o` returns all matches on the same line. You can get the first occurrence with `^.*?\K\bhello\b|^.*?\K\bhey\b|^.*?\K\bhi\b`

Comment: `echo -e 'hi\nhey\nhello' | grep -Poz '^.*?\K(?:\bhello\b|.*?\K\bhey\b|.*?\K\bhi\b)'` returns `hi` and is not what I want. With the previous formula, without the `g` modifier, the problem would be solved.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo `echo -e 'hi\nhey\nhello' | grep -Poz '(?s)(?:^.*?\K\bhello\b|^.*?\K\bhey\b|^.*?\K\bhi\b)'` now returns `hello`

Comment: Yes, you are right, because with `^` it is forced to match one alternative at a time because each of them starts from the beginning. best idea. This `(?:)` is not necessary.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo You are right, you can omit `(?:`